# Alternate Layouts on Oracle Reports Developer 6i

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I am working on several reports all of which have similar layouts I would like to know if there is a way to use one report and have alternating layouts based on a parameter. I am mainly concern with how the alternating layout is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple frames in an Oracle report, each of which show the same data in a different format; then put a format trigger on each that returns TRUE for one and FALSE for the other; and vice versa, depending on the parameter.

Alternatively, if the report is largely the same with minor differences, you can put the format triggers on just the items or boilerplate bits that need to be "switched on" or "off".

Comment: Thank you very much Jeffery Kemp